# how to make iScroll or iscrollview and Waypoints work together

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-waypoints, iscroll, iscrollview

Is there anyway i can make [jquerymobile-iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) and [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) work together. I am using iscrollview for smooth native scrolling on latest mobile devices & using waypoints for infinite scrolling. Currently, with both included, waypoints do not work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: you dont need both -- use iscroll js -- http://jsfiddle.net/enterzhu/6gRDL/ -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968141/jquery-mobile-listviews-lazy-loading

Comment: @Tasos Sure, but i have a huge code where waypoints have been used everywhere. Is there an easy fix where based on a iscroll event i trigger the waypoint or something like that. Or else i will have to spent lot of time converting the waypoints to iscroll pull events. Thanks!

Comment: are you lazy loading data and displaying on  screen as your scroll to the bottom with waypoints or do you use it for some other functionality?

Comment: @Tasos exactly as you mentioned !

Comment: so copy and paste the code from waypoints that feeds in more data to the iscroll (onscrollend) function -- and modify to make it work. Its your project so if you dont want to do that because you have a lot of code to adjust then its your decision not mine.

Comment: @Tasos You are right i need to eventually do that. But for now i need a quick fix. I found this link which helped [trigger scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924711/how-to-make-iscroll-and-lazy-load-jquery-plugins-work-together)